# Science Fiction novel from 40+ years ago

Tags: story-identification, novel

Plot: There are two super-intelligent beings that do not have any material manifestation. There were others of their species, that have either been destroyed or diminished in power. The remaining two are doing battle in very unique ways. They cannot locate each other physically, since they do not consist of matter. They launch tiny probes to circulate throughout their universe with a preordained path, and if the other being is encountered, the path is disturbed.  This path divergence indicates the presence of the other.

Comment: Hal Clement's Needle..? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needle_(novel)

Comment: Definitely not "Needle" -- that was about amoeboid aliens, which definitely counts as a material manifestation.